# Scaling a wavelet in continuous wavelet transform

Tags: frequency-spectrum, wavelet, gaussian, time-frequency

The mexican hat wavelet, obtained from the second derivative of a Gaussian, has a functional form of

$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{3 \sqrt{\pi} \sigma \ }} \left(1-\frac{t^2}{\sigma^2} \right) e^{-t^2/(2\sigma^2)} $$

where "$\sigma$ is the standard deviation of a Gaussian and $t$ is the independent variable.

If we graphically wish to graphically see its dilations, say at scale $1 \le a \le 5$, the typical form of a wavelet function $\psi$ has a scale parameter $a$ and a translation parameter $b$. The functional form of the Mexican hat given in MATLAB does not explicitly have them both.

The standard deviation $\sigma$ is the only variable here that controls with width, but this is not strictly equal to the scale $a$. How should we generate scaled versions of the Mexican hat?

Thanks.

[image: Mexican hat]

Comment: i think you substitute: $$ t \leftarrow \frac{t-b}{a} $$ to get this in terms of the wavelet params $a$ and $b$.  but $a$ and $\sigma$ always team up, so i would set $\sigma=1$ and just normalize the mother wavelet and let $a$ be the sole scaling factor.

Comment: I am familiar with the leftward arrow notation. Do you mean to say that we replace in the wavelet equation with (t-b)/a? It seems $a$ and $\sigma$ are inversely related. Larger the $a$  value, wider is the wavelet, in the wavelet literature. If this is the case, then this substitution would be valid. As per wavelet criterion, $\sigma$ has to be 0.68 in the Mexican hat.

Comment: yes, i am saying replace $t$ with $\frac{t-b}{a}$.  both $\sigma$ and $a$ divide into $t$, so i would think that they team up.  if one increases by a factor of 5 and the other decreases by the inverse ratio, the result will be the same wavelet.  "$b$" and "$a$" are simply other symbols to express the same translation and scaling that "$\mu$" and "$\sigma$" do.

Comment: You can do Latex for equations by yourself.  Start by right clicking on an equation and selecting "View math as tex".  You can also see RB-J's helpful addition to your post in edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I am not quite understanding your question.  Let's start with the definition of the Gaussian, aka the Bell Curve, in its general form.

$$  f(t) = \frac{1}{ \sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ -\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} } $$

$\mu$ is the mean, and represents where the peak occurs.

$\sigma$ is the standard deviation, and identifies where the inflection points are.

Taking the first derivative:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f'(t) & = \frac{1}{ \sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\left[ e^{ -\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} } \left( -\frac{(t-\mu)}{\sigma^2} \right) \right] \\
 & = - \frac{1}{ \sigma^3 \sqrt{2\pi}}\left[ e^{ -\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} } \left( t-\mu \right) \right] \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Taking the second derivative.

$$
\begin{aligned}
f''(t) &= - \frac{1}{ \sigma^3 \sqrt{2\pi}}\left[  e^{ -\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} } \left( -\frac{(t-\mu)}{\sigma^2} \right) \left( t-\mu \right) +
e^{ -\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }   \left( 1 \right)  \right] \\
f''(t) &=  \frac{1}{ \sigma^3 \sqrt{2\pi}}\left[    \frac{(t-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2} - 1 \right]  e^{ -\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} } \\
f''(t) &=  \frac{1}{ \sigma^3 \sqrt{2\pi}}\left[  \left( \frac{t-\mu}{\sigma} \right)^2 - 1 \right]  e^{ - \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{t-\mu}{\sigma} \right)^2 } \\
\end{aligned}
$$

In your example $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$.  In your graph, the zero is where the peak is, and the one is the +/-1 on your horizontal scale.  Notice that the second derivative is zero at these points (inflection in the original function.)

You can translate the graph by setting $\mu$.  You can stretch the graph horizontally by setting $\sigma$.

I am not familiar with wavelets, so I don't know what this $a$ and $b$ are that you are talking about.  You can definitely to another coordinate conversion if you want:

$$ t = a \tau + b $$

Gosh, but that is awfully similar to

$$ \frac{1}{\sigma} t - \frac{\mu}{\sigma} $$

that you already got.

---

Based on the comments, to retrofit the function call to MATLAB (or wherever):

$$ \mu = b $$

$$ \sigma = 0.63628 a $$

Comment: Thanks but understanding the translation part is easy that we shift the Mexican hat to a new time position which was originally $\mu$. Would you mind having a look at this section on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet#Continuous_wavelet_transforms_(continuous_shift_and_scale_parameters)

Comment: How can one bring the Mexican hat expression into the standard wavelet function form, which is psi_a,b(t)= 1/sqrt(a)psi((t-b)/a)? The value "a" shrinks or dilates the wavelet. It is always called a dilation in wavelet literature. In the Mexican hat expression, only sigma can shrink or dilate the second derivative. I am trying relate sigma with the scale parameter called "a". A larger value of "a" means a wider wavelet. So it seems a and sigma are inversely related.

Comment: i think it's, with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ then usually the only variable of a [mother wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet#Mother_wavelet) would be $$ t = \frac{\tau - b}{a}$$.  or maybe $t$ and $\tau$ are swapped.

Comment: i dunno, Ced, the wikipedia definition for Mexican hat is $$ \psi(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3\sigma}\pi^{1/4}} \left(1 - \left(\frac{t}{\sigma}\right)^2 \right) e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$ which is consistent with the OP.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I just derived the second derivative.  It is a rescaled (normalized?) version of wiki formula with $\mu=0$.

Comment: @M.Farooq When you plug 

$$ \frac{t-b}{a} $$

in for $t$ within $ \frac{t}{\sigma} $ you simply get:

$$ \frac{t-b}{a\sigma} $$

So adjusting $a$ and $\sigma$ have reciprical effect from each other.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, because $a$ would be essentially increasing the standard deviation. In wavelets, larger $a$ >0, should widen the wavelet.

Comment: @M.Farooq You're welcome.  As RB-J suggested, you might just set $\sigma=1$ and use $a$ for your scaling factor.  It will work just like the $\sigma$.

Comment: @CedronDawg, for some reasons in wavelet, the $\sigma$ has to be 0.63628 by definition for the mexican hat.

Comment: @M.Farooq Seems to me your next research topic should be knowing that reason.  It is probably a normalization thing (Setting an area to 1 or something).  Then use $a$ to stretch it.

Comment: Yes, I am a chemist and using wavelets to denoise some signals. It is indeed for normalization and fulfill the criteria of a wavelet definition.